# Understanding the OVERRUN error for a duplex SPI communication with nrf24l01 radio module

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, embedded, nrf24l01

So I am using an HAL library for SPI to talk with the radio module. I configured the SPI to be bidirectional or full-duplex so the master receives the data from the MISO line as it sends out on the MOSI.

The issue that I am seeing is I receive an OVERRUN error the moment SPI is enabled (`SPE`), and the HAL function has a check for OVERRUN for RX mode only, so it doesn't execute the RX handling but sends out the specified number of bytes (not even sure if they're being sent anyways).

In the reference manual, I see it says when the data is ready to be sent to the slave but the rx buffer is still full. My understanding is in a full-duplex communication, the data is written to `DR` from the rx buffer that gets data from the MOSI line and the latest piece of data in the tx buffer gets sent to MISO line. So assuming data is being continuously sent, what does overrun really indicate?

**EDIT: MCU - STM32F401 nucleo
Also, when I tried to connect the SCLK pin to the logic analyzer, I didn't see anything. Does the above mentioned behavior indicate if the issue might be with the slave itself?**

The following is the HAL function snippet:

```
void HAL_SPI_IRQHandler(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
  uint32_t itsource = hspi->Instance->CR2;
  uint32_t itflag   = hspi->Instance->SR;

  /* SPI in mode Receiver ----------------------------------------------------*/
  if ((SPI_CHECK_FLAG(itflag, SPI_FLAG_OVR) == RESET) &&
      (SPI_CHECK_FLAG(itflag, SPI_FLAG_RXNE) != RESET) && (SPI_CHECK_IT_SOURCE(itsource, SPI_IT_RXNE) != RESET))
  {
    hspi->RxISR(hspi);
    return;
  }

  /* SPI in mode Transmitter -------------------------------------------------*/
  if ((SPI_CHECK_FLAG(itflag, SPI_FLAG_TXE) != RESET) && (SPI_CHECK_IT_SOURCE(itsource, SPI_IT_TXE) != RESET))
  {
    hspi->TxISR(hspi);
    return;
  }
```

```
static void SPI_RxISR_8BIT(struct __SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
  *hspi->pRxBuffPtr = (*(__IO uint8_t *)&hspi->Instance->DR);
  hspi->pRxBuffPtr++;
  hspi->RxXferCount--;

#if (USE_SPI_CRC != 0U)
  /* Enable CRC Transmission */
  if ((hspi->RxXferCount == 1U) && (hspi->Init.CRCCalculation == SPI_CRCCALCULATION_ENABLE))
  {
    SET_BIT(hspi->Instance->CR1, SPI_CR1_CRCNEXT);
  }
#endif /* USE_SPI_CRC */

  if (hspi->RxXferCount == 0U)
  {
#if (USE_SPI_CRC != 0U)
    if (hspi->Init.CRCCalculation == SPI_CRCCALCULATION_ENABLE)
    {
      hspi->RxISR =  SPI_RxISR_8BITCRC;
      return;
    }
#endif /* USE_SPI_CRC */
    SPI_CloseRx_ISR(hspi);
  }
}
```

That's what I'm trying to achieve with a write operation
[image]

Following is how I am configuring the SPI peripheral:

````
// main.c

nrfl2401 nrfRadio;

void nRF24_GPIO_Init(void)
{
    // configure CE and SCN
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioPort;
    gpioPort.Pin = rNRF24_CE_PIN;
    gpioPort.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    gpioPort.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    gpioPort.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(nRF24_GPIO_PORT, &gpioPort);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(nRF24_GPIO_PORT, gpioPort.Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    gpioPort.Pin = rNRF24_CSN_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(nRF24_GPIO_PORT, &gpioPort);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(nRF24_GPIO_PORT, gpioPort.Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    gpioPort.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    gpioPort.Pin = SPI_SCLK_PIN;
    gpioPort.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI_SCLK_PORT, &gpioPort);

    gpioPort.Pin = SPI_MOSI_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI_MOSI_PORT, &gpioPort);

    gpioPort.Pin = SPI_MISO_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI_MISO_PORT, &gpioPort);
}

void SPI_Init(SPI_InitTypeDef *SPI_Config, SPI_TypeDef *SPIx)
{
    SPI_handle.Instance = SPIx;
    SPI_handle.Init = *SPI_Config;

    __HAL_RCC_SPI2_CLK_ENABLE();
    HAL_SPI_Init(&SPI_handle);
}

void nRF24_Init(nrfl2401_Config *radioConfig)
{
    nRF24_GPIO_Init();
    nrfRadio.config = *radioConfig;
    nRF24_Initialization(&nrfRadio);
}

int main(void) {
   // ...
   SPI_InitTypeDef spi_config = {
            Mode: SPI_MODE_MASTER,
            Direction: SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE, 
            DataSize: SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT,
            CLKPolarity: SPI_POLARITY_LOW,
            CLKPhase: SPI_PHASE_1EDGE,
            NSS: SPI_NSS_SOFT,
            BaudRatePrescaler: SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_8, 
            FirstBit: SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB,
            TIMode: SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE,
            CRCCalculation: SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE,
            CRCPolynomial: 7
    };
    SPI_Init(&spi_config, SPI2);

    nrfl2401_Config radioConfig = {
            spiHandle: &SPI_handle
    };
    nRF24_Init(&radioConfig);
    
    while (1);
}

// radio.c
void nRF24_Initialization(nrfl2401 *nrf)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(nRF24_GPIO_PORT, rNRF24_CE_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET); // chip enable
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(nRF24_GPIO_PORT, rNRF24_CSN_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // chip select

    nRF24_WriteRegister(nrf, nRF24_CONFIG_REG, 0x8);
}

void nRF24_WriteRegister(nrfl2401 *nrf, uint8_t reg, uint8_t data)
{
    uint8_t txBuffer[2] = {0};
    uint8_t rxBuffer[2] = {0};

    txBuffer[0] = nRF24_CMD_W_REG | (reg & nRF24_R_W_MASK);
    txBuffer[1] = data;
    HAL_StatusTypeDef txRx = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT(nrf->config.spiHandle, txBuffer, rxBuffer, 2);
    while (nrf->config.spiHandle->State != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
}```
````

Comment: What do you do in the byte complete or transfer complete callbacks?

Comment: are you referring to `HAL_SPI_TxCpltCallback()`? haven't implemented it yet but it's more application specific, no? and is it related to this issue? for the Tx complete callback, I guess I'd just be storing the data received from MISO line somewhere

Comment: Can you post the RxISR too? I don't want to guess which STM32 HAL this is. Also mention which MCU.

Comment: edited..........

Comment: Either that is not the full code, or there is something wrong with it. Do you even initialize nrf->config.spiHandle to point to SPI2?

Comment: my bad. i didn't show that part. edited. also, the spiHandle is of type `SPI_HandleTypeDef` and SPI2 is of type `SPI_TypeDef*`

Comment: I think you should set `spi_config.Direction` to `SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES` if you want bi-directional communication on MOSI and MISO.

Comment: @kkrambo - full duplex mode is  (BIDIMODE=0, RXONLY=0)

Comment: Right, if you want full duplex you need two separate data lines for MOSI and MISO.  And BIDIMODE should be 0.  That's what setting Direction to SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES does.  SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE sets BIDIMODE = 1.  SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE is for half duplex, which is bidirectional on one data line.

Comment: I noticed you enable the clocks for the SPI2 peripheral, but do you enable clocks for the GPIO pins?